# Run a compiled iPhone Simulator App Build? (.app) without Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

So have a complete build of my app compatible for the iOS Simulator on Snow Leopard. Now I don't want to install Xcode on my other Mac to run this.

The question: Is there a way to only install the iOS Simulator? I could install the app on my iOS Simulator on my primary Mac and then just copy the iPhone Simulator folder from the Library folder and paste it on my secondary Mac.

Or is there any other app?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Simulator Launcher](https://github.com/landonf/simlaunch/):

> Simulator Launcher builds custom executables to automatically launch an
>   embedded iPhone Simulator application using the correct iPhone SDK.

Comment: Currently, Simulator Launcher fails if you try to run on Xcode 4.2.1 because Xcode moved the location of its internals (frameworks and etc.) https://github.com/landonf/simlaunch/issues/8

Answer (score 1):

The Simulator app depends on other directories and files in the SDK/Xcode installation.  Best bet is to install the full iOS SDK and then try deleting Xcode and other stuff until you find the minimum required.

There is no other app.

Answer (score 0):

ios-sim seems to be the only one that works with xcode 6.3
https://github.com/phonegap/ios-sim

Answer (score -1):

Try using app.io, worked great for me, and it's free