# How to run iOS .app package within Simulator?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Dev guys from other company, sent me iOS app package that is build with Xcode, but I don't have its Xcode project, just built app package file. How to run that on simulator or on iphone?

UDPATE: I'v tried [Simulator launcher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121790/run-a-compiled-iphone-simulator-app-build-app-without-xcode/5121970) but the solution is not working when using Xcode 4.2.1.

UPDATE2: Also tried to use this [solution](http://cocoamanifest.net/articles/2011/12/running-your-ios-app-in-the-simulator-from-the-command-line.html) but with no luck (getting black simulator screen and errors shown in terminal after launch). IMHO these problems might be related to iOS 5

UPDATE3: Also, unsuccessfully, tried to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187611/how-to-install-iphone-application-in-iphone-simulator)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'app package?' do you mean a `.ipa`, a `.app`, or what exactly? Also, make sure the bundle you are trying to launch is built for the simulator, not the device.

Comment: Tell them about testflightapp.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally you should be able to install it with itunes, a detailed step-by step guide can be found here: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Ad-hoc-iPhone-OS-Apps

Answer (score 1):

If it is built for device, you can install it to your device using iTunes or Xcode Organizer. However, you cannot run it on any device. They should also give you a provisioning profile for letting you install that app on your device.

Comment: Yes, they also sent me provisioning profile. Could you describe how to install that app using Xcode organizer? I tried looking there but not found how to do that... In viewing in organizer with connected device, I can see my existing apps, but "Add" button is disabled at the bottom of screen.

Comment: Try double clicking the provisioning profile. It should automatically open in Xcode. Once you have the provisioning profile u should be able to install the app, either via iTunes or Xcode Organizer as murat said.

Comment: Yes, but how to install that? Add button is disabled, and dragging .app file to organizer (to iPhone application) is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I'v asked the guys to send me "ipa" package instead of raw .app package. Then added it to my iPhone device.

Comment: So, did you decide to just skip trying to run it in the simulator and just test on the device?